# javascript コンソールの表示が変

Tags: javascript

初歩的ですみませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上に表示した配列は、配列が5つ入っているはずですが、クリックしても要素が一つしかなくlengthも1となっています。こんなのは見たことがありません。どういう状況かおわかりでしたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コンソールに表示した時点での値が表示されるので、「`console.dir()`を実行した時点の変数の内容」と「コンソール上で内容を展開したときの変数の内容」が異なることがあります。

下の例では`console.dir()`実行時は要素数2、内容展開時は`arr.push(3)`の後なので要素数3になります。

```html
<script>
let arr = [];
arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
console.dir(arr);

arr.push(3);
</script>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そうとは知りませんでした。非同期でループしてる場合その時々の変数は見られないのですかね。調べてみます。ありがとうございました。